# RecyclerView with different items (group and child items)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am doing a `RecyclerView` that will have two different items, but I don't know how I can do that.

First: I have a `ArrayList` of an object and I don't know how put the times related with the date in the `RecyclerView`.

- Date - Group item.
- Times - Child item.

  ```
   Object {
   Date date;
   ArrayList times;
   }
  ```

Second: how I can change the spanSize according the item in adapter, when the position of the item isn't expected? (`GridLayoutManager`)

Answer (score 4):

To answer your second part, to change the span size depending on the item type (group or child), you set the Span Size Lookup on the `GridLayoutManager`. In your adapter, you implement `getItemViewType()` and return a view type depending on the position. E.g. 0 for group, 1 for child, in which case `MyAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_GROUP` would be 0.

```
RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(
        R.id.my_fragment_my_recycler_view);
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 5);
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        if (list.getAdapter().getItemViewType(position) == MyAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_GROUP) {
            // return the number of columns so the group header takes a whole row
            return 5
        }
        // normal child item takes up 1 cell
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) to group your items in sections and add a header to each section:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String date;
    List<String> list;

    public MySection(String date, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.date = date;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(date);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your sections and change the spanSize of the header with a GridLayoutManager:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data
MySection date1Section = new MySection("Date 1", date1List);
MySection date2Section = new MySection("Date 2", date2List);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(date1Section);
sectionAdapter.addSection(date2Section);

// set up a gridlayoutmanager to change the spansize of the header
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        switch(sectionAdapter.getSectionItemViewType(position)) {
            case SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_HEADER:
                return 2;
            default:
                return 1;
        }
    }
});

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```